# How to give values to structure variable if it is in const enum in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum 
{
  aa = 11, 
  bb = 13
}
data2;

typedef struct
{
  int cc;
  const data2 dd;
}
data1;

int main() 
{
  // HOW TO GIVE VALUES TO data2.dd?? 

  printf("%d", data2.dd) ;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Even for experts it's It's hard to work with unreadable code.

Comment: What's the actual question here, how to initialize a struct? It has nothing to do with enums as such: `data1 foo = {123,aa}; printf("%d", foo.dd);`

Answer (score 3):

Like any `const` object it can only be set in the initializer.

```
data1 d = { .dd = aa };
```

Answer (score 1):

`data2` and `data1` are not objects only **type names** same as `int` or `float`.  It is not very good to use the same names for types and struct members (use your imagination and give them some meaningful names).

To set the value:

```
data1 data3 = {.dd = bb};
```

to access

```
printf("%d", data3.dd) ;
```

Comment: `data3.data2` is enum. It will not compile

Comment: @tstanisl Yes noticed - those names are so so confusing.